# Synaptics two-finger-tap right-click happens on non-tap

Tags: scrolling, synaptic

Pardon the horrendous title, I'm not exactly sure how to summarize the issue I'm having. Basically, I have synaptics, and I right-click by tapping two fingers on the touchpad because my touchpad doesn't have any buttons. This is great, but I get all sorts of extra right-clicks because unlike left-clicking (tapping with a single finger), the right-click doesn't require the contact to be brief.

Left-click (single-finger) requires the tap to be a tap, i.e. if I put a finger on the touchpad, leave it there for a moment, and then raise it, it is *not* a click. That's great.

Right-click (double-finger) does not require a tap, i.e. if I put two fingers on the touchpad, leave them there for a moment, and then raise them, it *is* a right click, thrown when my fingers leave the touchpad. This is a problem.

It's especially annoying because I use two-finger scroll, so I get random right-click events if I didn't scroll enough, or was going to scroll then decided not to, etc. How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs here. Unless the problem is specific to Unix or Linux? I mean, does the computer have multiple operating systems on it and is this issue only with the Linux side?

Comment: i would imagine this would happen to anyone using two-finger scroll with Synaptics under Linux... I could be wrong though because my sample size is, you know, one.

Comment: From what I read in `man synaptics`, scrolling area and tapping are the same, the *Synaptics Area*. I'd suggest: a) switch to *Three-Finger Tap* for right-click, b) use *Corner Button* for right-click, c) switch to *Edge Scroll*.